# Incorrect Syntax Near

Tags: asp.net

I am  new to asp.net i receive an error about incorrect syntax near ')' I don't have any idea how to fix this please help me thanks in advance

Comment: You have an [SQL-Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx) vulnerability, use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Comment: print out the resulting `CommandText` and inspect that. Any chance of an embedded `'` in the textbox values?

Comment: its probably an SQL syntax error, post some code.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, you should use parametrized queries. Here's a simplified example with 2 columns:

```
Using conn = New SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString)
    Using cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
        conn.open()
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnName1, ColumnName2) Values(@value1, @value2)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", lbl_value1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", lbl_value2.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Now adapt my example to your table schema.